# Decrypt file encrypted using openssl with aes-cbc-256

Tags: java, ssl, aes

I have encrypted a file using below commands

openssl rand 32 > test.key

openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -iter 10000 -pbkdf2 -salt -in test.txt -out test.txt.enc -pass file:test.key

Now i am trying to decrypt it using java. tring since last few days but no success.

Can anyone help ?

my code

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class OpenSSlDecryptor {
    private static final Charset ASCII = Charset.forName("ASCII");
    private static final int INDEX_KEY = 0;
    private static final int INDEX_IV = 1;
    private static final int ITERATIONS = 10000;

    private static final int ARG_INDEX_FILENAME = 0;
    private static final int ARG_INDEX_PASSWORD = 1;

    private static final int SALT_OFFSET = 8;
    private static final int SALT_SIZE = 8;
    private static final int CIPHERTEXT_OFFSET = SALT_OFFSET + SALT_SIZE;

    private static final int KEY_SIZE_BITS = 256;

    /**
     * Thanks go to Ola Bini for releasing this source on his blog.
     * The source was obtained from <a href="http://olabini.com/blog/tag/evp_bytestokey/">here</a> .
     */
    public static byte[][] EVP_BytesToKey(final int key_len, final int iv_len, final MessageDigest md,
            final byte[] salt, final byte[] data, final int count) {
        final byte[][] both = new byte[2][];
        final byte[] key = new byte[key_len];
        int key_ix = 0;
        final byte[] iv = new byte[iv_len];
        int iv_ix = 0;
        both[0] = key;
        both[1] = iv;
        byte[] md_buf = null;
        int nkey = key_len;
        int niv = iv_len;
        int i = 0;
        if (data == null) {
            return both;
        }
        int addmd = 0;
        for (;;) {
            md.reset();
            if (addmd++ > 0) {
                md.update(md_buf);
            }
            md.update(data);
            if (null != salt) {
                md.update(salt, 0, 8);
            }
            md_buf = md.digest();
            for (i = 1; i < count; i++) {
                md.reset();
                md.update(md_buf);
                md_buf = md.digest();
            }
            i = 0;
            if (nkey > 0) {
                for (;;) {
                    if (nkey == 0) {
                      break;
                    }
                    if (i == md_buf.length) {
                      break;
                    }
                    key[key_ix++] = md_buf[i];
                    nkey--;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            if (niv > 0 && i != md_buf.length) {
                for (;;) {
                    if (niv == 0) {
                      break;
                    }
                    if (i == md_buf.length) {
                      break;
                    }
                    iv[iv_ix++] = md_buf[i];
                    niv--;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            if (nkey == 0 && niv == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < md_buf.length; i++) {
            md_buf[i] = 0;
        }
        return both;
    }


    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
     final String fileName = "test.txt.enc";

      final File f = new File(fileName );
      try {
            // --- read base 64 encoded file ---

            List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f))) {
              //br returns as stream and convert it into a List
              lines = br.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());

          } catch (final IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

            final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (final String line : lines) {
                sb.append(line.trim());
            }


            final String random_bin_key = "test.key";
            final byte[] passwordKey = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(random_bin_key));

            // --- extract salt & encrypted ---
            final byte[] headerSaltAndCipherText = sb.toString().getBytes();
            // header is "Salted__", ASCII encoded, if salt is being used (the default)
            final byte[] salt = Arrays.copyOfRange(
                    headerSaltAndCipherText, SALT_OFFSET, SALT_OFFSET + SALT_SIZE);
            final byte[] encrypted = Arrays.copyOfRange(
                    headerSaltAndCipherText, CIPHERTEXT_OFFSET, headerSaltAndCipherText.length);

            // --- specify cipher and digest for EVP_BytesToKey method ---

            final Cipher aesCBC = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            final MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

            // --- create key and IV  ---

            // the IV is useless, OpenSSL might as well have use zero's
            final byte[][] keyAndIV = EVP_BytesToKey(
                    KEY_SIZE_BITS / Byte.SIZE,
                    aesCBC.getBlockSize(),
                    md5,
                    salt,
                    passwordKey,
                    ITERATIONS);
            final SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyAndIV[INDEX_KEY], "AES");
            final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(keyAndIV[INDEX_IV]);

            // --- initialize cipher instance and decrypt ---

            aesCBC.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
            final byte[] decrypted = aesCBC.doFinal(encrypted);
            final String answer = new String(decrypted);
            System.out.println(answer);
        } catch (final BadPaddingException e) {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (final IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (final GeneralSecurityException e) {
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (final IOException e) {
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
}
```

Error i am getting

```
Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
```

I refereed following link

https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Encrypt_and_decrypt_files_to_public_keys_via_the_OpenSSL_Command_Line.html

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/How-do-I-decrypt-AES-256-CBC-data-in-HDF-if-it-was-encrypted/td-p/97961#

tried with

```
` final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
    // strip off the salt and iv
    final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(encryptedText);
    byte[] saltBytes = new byte[16];
    buffer.get(saltBytes, 0, saltBytes.length);
    saltBytes =  Arrays.copyOfRange(saltBytes, 8, 16);
    final byte[] ivBytes1 = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
    buffer.get(ivBytes1, 0, ivBytes1.length);
    final int length = buffer.capacity() - 16 - ivBytes1.length;
    // length = length+ 16 -(length%16);
    final byte[] encryptedTextBytes = new byte[length];

    buffer.get(encryptedTextBytes);
    // Deriving the key
     final SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
     final PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(new String(password).toCharArray(), saltBytes, 10000,
    256);
     final SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);
     final SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes1));
    byte[] decryptedTextBytes = null;
    try {
      decryptedTextBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedTextBytes);
    } catch (final IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (final BadPaddingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Getting badpadding exception

tried with `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256` still getting the error

Comment: Since you haven't shown us what you've tried it's impossible for anyone to tell what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I have added my code

Comment: Well, it looks to me like you're using different key derivation functions for encryption and decryption. When you encrypt you're using PBKDF2, but for decryption you appear to be using some older function, and probably end up with a completely different key. Can't you just use `javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory` to do PBKDF2 in your Java code?

Comment: @Michael i tried but getting bad padding exception, sometime corrupt padding

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256"`?

Comment: Getting the same error `javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted
 at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2164)
 `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems. The most obvious is that you are trying to read the IV from the file, but `openssl enc` in its default password-based mode derives both key and IV from password and salt -- even when using PBKDF2. However, both the standard (Sun/Oracle/OpenJDK) and BouncyCastle providers in Java implement PBKDF2 to derive only a key -- the way it is used in *PBES2*.

Even without that, your method of generating the 'password' as random bytes wouldn't work either. The [PKCS5 standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8018#section-3) actually defines PBKDF2 to take the password as

> an octet
> string of arbitrary length whose interpretation as a text string is
> unspecified.  In the interest of interoperability, however, it is
> recommended that applications follow some common text encoding rules.
> ASCII and UTF-8 [RFC3629] are two possibilities.  (ASCII is a subset
> of UTF-8.)

Many systems take interoperable encoding more seriously, and Java in particular (which was designed from its inception to be worldwide) defines `PBEKeySpec` to contain *characters* -- `char[]` in Java is UTF-16 -- which are encoded as UTF-8 when doing PBKDF2. In contrast `openssl` is a C program dating from before the turn of the century when C started admitting the existence of countries other than the USA, so it only knows about bytes -- bytes which *might* be ASCII, or some other single-byte code like EBCDIC, but maybe not characters at all and certainly not any of those weird foreign characters that don't fit in a byte. The probability of a sequence of 32 random bytes being valid UTF-8 is very low; it's too much work for me to figure analytically, but I ran a test of 100 million random values and got only one that would work with your scheme. (I was going to test a billion but got tired of waiting.)

Plus, since a password is supposed to be text, `openssl` reads `-pass file:` as a *text* file and treats it as a string. That means if any of the random bytes is a null byte or a byte corresponding to the newline character, the remainder of the data in the file is discarded and ignored for the key-and-IV derivation. This will occur on average about 1 in 4 times for random 32-byte values, and about 1 in 20 times it will occur early enough in the file to make the result cryptographically weak and breakable.

Which raises the point: why are you using password-based encryption at all? If your 'key' is 32 bytes from a decent secure RNG -- which `openssl rand` is -- you don't need to strengthen it, it's already valid as a key. You can use `openssl enc` to do **key-based** encryption, not password-based, and it's more efficient, more secure, AND much easier in Java -- a massive win. *IF* you use a new, random key for each encryption you don't even have to use a real IV, you can just use a zero IV as I did below. But if you are going to *reuse* the/any key, you need to use a unique and unpredictable -- normally random -- IV for each encryption, and convey it with the data, perhaps by just putting it at the front.

So anyway, here's a fairly simple Java program which can handle either case: the openssl form of pdbkf2 with a 'password' that isn't actually a password and isn't UTF-8, or the more sensible key-based form (but for this demo with zero IV):

```
//nopackage
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;

public class SO61613286 {
    static public void main (String[] args) throws Exception /* let JVM give error */{
        // arguments: P/K, filename output from openssl enc, filename of text pw or binary key
        byte[] file = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(args[1])); 
        byte[] fil2 = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(args[2])); 
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        
        if( args[0].startsWith("P") ){
            // possibly truncate 'password' in fil2
            int n = 0; for( ; n < fil2.length; n++ ) if( fil2[n]==0 || fil2[n]=='\n' ) break;
            if( n < fil2.length ) fil2 = Arrays.copyOf(fil2, n);
            // extract salt and derive ...
            byte[] salt = Arrays.copyOfRange(file, 8, 16);
            byte[] derive = PBKDF2 ("HmacSHA256", fil2, salt, 10000, 48);
            // ... key is first 32, IV is last 16
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(derive,0,32,"AES"), new IvParameterSpec(derive,32,16));
            // remainder of file is ciphertext
            System.out.write( cipher.doFinal(file,16,file.length-16) );
        }else{
            // just use fil2 as key and zeros for IV ...
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(fil2,"AES"), new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));
            // ... all of file is ciphertext
            System.out.write( cipher.doFinal(file,0,file.length) );
            // !!!if key will be reused, must use better IVs and transmit with the data!!!
        }
    }
    public static byte[] PBKDF2 (String prf, byte[] pass, byte[] salt, int iter, int len)
            throws NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {
        byte[] result = new byte[len];
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(prf);
        mac.init (new SecretKeySpec (pass,prf));
        byte[] saltcnt = Arrays.copyOf (salt, salt.length+4);
        while( /*remaining*/len>0 ){
            for( int o = saltcnt.length; --o>=saltcnt.length-4; ) if( ++saltcnt[o] != 0 ) break; 
            byte[] u = saltcnt, x = new byte[mac.getMacLength()];
            for( int i = 1; i <= iter; i++ ){
                u = mac.doFinal (u); 
                for( int o = 0; o < x.length; o++ ) x[o] ^= u[o];
            }
            int len2 = Math.min (len, x.length);
            System.arraycopy (x,0, result,result.length-len, len2);
            len -= len2;
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static void testutf8 (){
        Random r = new Random();
        byte[] t = new byte[32];
        for( int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++ ){
            r.nextBytes(t); 
            if( Arrays.equals(new String (t, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), t) ) 
                System.out.println(i+" "+Arrays.toString(t));
            if( i % 1000000 == 999999 ) System.out.println (i);
        }
    }
}
```

and a demo:

```
$ openssl rand 32 >SO61613286.rnd   # repeated several times until I got this:
$ xxd SO61613286.rnd   # notice the null byte
0000000: ab1a 1384 9238 0900 c947 6b9a c23d 5ee0  .....8...Gk..=^.
0000010: 32f0 6b2f 91ec 2dd9 a69d eb7d e00e 37ff  2.k/..-....}..7.
$
$ echo the name of the cat >SO61613286.in
$
$ openssl aes-256-cbc -in SO61613286.in -out SO61613286.enc1 -pass file:SO61613286.rnd -pbkdf2 -iter 10000
$ java8 -cp . SO61613286 P SO61613286.enc1 SO61613286.rnd
the name of the cat
$
$ openssl aes-256-cbc -in SO61613286.in -out SO61613286.enc2 -K $(xxd -p -c32 SO61613286.rnd) -iv 00
hex string is too short, padding with zero bytes to length
$ # that's a warning and can be ignored, as long as we don't need real IVs (see above)
$ java8 -cp . SO61613286 K SO61613286.enc2 SO61613286.rnd      
the name of the cat
$
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, you made my day :)